# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'photutils.geometry.circular_overlap

Tags: module, google-colaboratory, sys, astropy, photutils

I'm trying to install the latest version of **photutils** (version 1.5) on my google-colab. Since it requires python >= 3.8, I first install python 3.8 using the code below. I also change the sys.path, and I install photutils successfully using pip.
The problem is that when I **import photutils** I get the following Error. I also tried to install photutils using conda but the result is the same.

```css
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/sitepackages/photutils/geometry/__init__.py in <module>()
      4 """
      5 
----> 6 from .circular_overlap import *  # noqa
      7 from .elliptical_overlap import *  # noqa
      8 from .rectangular_overlap import *  # noqa

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'photutils.geometry.circular_overlap
```

```css
#Here is how I install python 3.8 on my colab:

!wget -O mini.sh https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py38_4.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x mini.sh
!bash ./mini.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!conda install -q -y --prefix /usr/local jupyter
!python -m ipykernel install --name "py38" --user

import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/')
```

```css
!pip install photutils==1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you try install photutils most recently version?

```
!pip install photutils
```

Photutils is in 1.6 version.
https://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: I just tried it! The Python in google-colab has been upgraded to 3.8, which I was trying to install a couple of months ago. Now everything is fine, and I can import the newest photutils easily. Thank you for mentioning this here:)

Comment: This does not work in Windows 10, March, 2023. It keeps throwing the same error.

Comment: Are you using Python 3.8 on Windows 10? or google-Colab?